# modals wont close when created using template literals

Tags: javascript, iframe, modal-dialog, template-literals

I have an image gallery which has modals for each image.
The gallery and modals are created in javascript using template literals.
The modals pop ups are different html files imported using iframe.

For some reason the modals won't close when clicking outside.
I tried creating the iframes inside the html instead of using template literals and I had no problems in that case, just when using javascript for making them.

Here is an example of what is happening.
[THIS GITHUB EXAMPLE](https://afxcrush.github.io/modal-with-template-literal-test/)

This is the modal function used in both cases:

```
function modalLinks(tempgal){
    let btnId = "btn" + tempgal.imgn;
    let modId = "id" + tempgal.imgn;
    let getBtnId = document.getElementById(btnId);
    let getModId = document.getElementById(modId);
    getBtnId.onclick = function() {
        console.log('click: btn: ' + this.id + ', modal: ' + getModId.id);
        getModId.classList.toggle('show-popup');
    }
    /* to dispose the popup on click */
    getModId.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.id +" it's OK");
        this.classList.toggle('show-popup');
    }
}
```

The moon and its modal are created inside of the HTML.
The other two images (sorry if they don't show properly) are created using template literals, and, as you can see (if you already saw the example), the moon modal works fine but the other two don't.

It'll be great if someone please tell me what is happening.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just experimented changing things and moving others and got the solution.
When making modals with external html's and importing them with iframe, putting the iframe within a div is the best choice.

The iframed modal shoul look like this

```
<div id="modalid" class="modal-window">
    <iframe class="modal-wrap" src="thelink" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

the css like this

```
.modal-window{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.modal-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

and the html imported must have this class

```
.modalcontent{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```